# SQL Server join query to fetch data based groupby though sure

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables for example for creating report on subject linked with photo album. Each id contains multiple images. When I generate report I get report with each photo. please guide.

TABLE A

```
no  CODE_id      DETAIL
1      1         HOMEPHOTOS
2      2         school
```

TABLE B

```
    no  CODE_id TITLE   IMAGE
    1   1   MYHOME  MYHOME.JPG
    2   1   HOME    HOME.JPG
    3   1   FLOWER  GARDEN.JPG
    4   2   POOL    POOL.JPG
    5   2   class   class.jpg
    6   2   play    play.jpg
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    dbo.TEST_123.CODE_id,
    dbo.TEST_123.DETAIL,
    dbo.TEST_XYZ.TITLE,
    dbo.TEST_XYZ.IMAGE
FROM
    dbo.TEST_123
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TEST_XYZ ON (dbo.TEST_123.CODE_id = dbo.TEST_XYZ.CODE_id);
```

I get this result:

```
CODE_id DETAIL  TITLE   IMAGE
--------------------------------------
1   HOMEPHOTOS  MYHOME  MYHOME.JPG
1   HOMEPHOTOS  HOME    HOME.JPG
1   HOMEPHOTOS  FLOWER  GARDEN.JPG
2   school      POOL    POOL.JPG
2   school      class   class.jpg
2   school      play    play.jpg
```

While I want result like this:

```
CODE_id  DETAIL         TITLE   IMAGE
---------------------------------------------
1        HOMEPHOTOS     MYHOME  MYHOME.JPG
                        HOME    HOME.JPG
                        FLOWER  GARDEN.JPG

2        school         POOL    POOL.JPG
                        class   class.jpg
                        play    play.jpg
```

Please guide me, maybe `group by` is required but I am unable to figure out how.

Comment: Those 2 results are the same!

Comment: This is a **display** problem - SQL Server returns the proper data - now it's up to your GUI or report to properly format it as needed

Comment: you can do this on application level..if the text value is same as previous print it else don't print it.

Comment: hi @ssss, you can actually do this using sql window functions (e.g ROW_NUMBER)

Comment: You can do this in your report too..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and display blank on repeating data if it already exist.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.TEST_123.CODE_id ORDER BY dbo.TEST_123.CODE_id) = 1
                THEN dbo.TEST_123.CODE_id
                ELSE NULL
    END [CODE_id],
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.TEST_123.CODE_id, dbo.TEST_123.DETAIL ORDER BY dbo.TEST_123.CODE_id) = 1
                THEN dbo.TEST_123.DETAIL
                ELSE NULL
    END [DETAIL],
    dbo.TEST_XYZ.TITLE,
    dbo.TEST_XYZ.IMAGE
FROM
    dbo.TEST_123
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TEST_XYZ ON (dbo.TEST_123.CODE_id = dbo.TEST_XYZ.CODE_id);
```

But you can also format your data in the application level. Its your call anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

Use ROW_NUMBER() to get index of each group then display detail when group index is 1 else empty string.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT DETAIL,CODE_id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODE_id ORDER BY CODE_id) as indx
    FROM dbo.TEST_123
)


SELECT
     CTE.CODE_id,
     CASE WHEN CTE.indx=1 THEN CTE.DETAIL ELSE '' END,
     dbo.TEST_XYZ.TITLE,
     dbo.TEST_XYZ.IMAGE
FROM
     CTE
INNER JOIN
dbo.TEST_XYZ ON (CTE.CODE_id = dbo.TEST_XYZ.CODE_id);
```